# DBMS using index to increase performance (with example)

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, database

```
select s.name,c.name,r.edition,r.grade
from students s, courses c, registrations r
where s.student_id=r.student_id
and r.course_id=c.course_id
and r.grade > 10
order by 1,2,3;
```

Creating and index in "grade" column will improve this query performance?

Comment: I might be answering myself but if we use an index in 'grade' (i'm imagining a simple binary tree) we don't need to scan all the table to get values greater than, for example, 10. Using an index, we could evaluate a lot let of rows due to the fact the the data is 'sorted' and easy to get a specific value. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Creating and index in "grade" column will improve this query performance?

Possibly - it depends on how disperse the values in the `grade` column are - if 99% (for sake of argument) of the values are `> 10`, the compiler might decide that it's not worth the trouble of using the index when it's going to have to basically scan the table anyways.

Answer (score 2):

*ALMOST* any field being used to filter query results will benefit from indexing, so yes, an index on `grade` will most likely help.

Moving away from old-style joins won't improve performance but it's a good idea:

```
SELECT s.name,c.name,r.edition,r.grade
FROM registrations r
JOIN courses c
 ON r.course_id=c.course_id
JOIN students s
 ON s.student_id=r.student_id
WHERE r.grade > 10
ORDER BY s.name,c.name,r.edition
```